# How to filter a GetPaged in SubSonic 3.0 using ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm attempting to filter a GetPaged() result using SubSonic 3.0 but I haven't been able to find a way.
I've tried using the following:

```
var list = Class.Find(filter);
var paged = new SubSonic.Schema.PagedList<Class>(list, 1, 10);
```

This doesn't appear to work, I'm getting a cannot convert error and this would go against the reason for paging, as I'd be pulling the entire list from the database.

If anyone has a method to retrieve a filtered paged list using SubSonic 3.0 it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a question regarding subsoinc you should always say if you are using ActiveRecord, LinqTemplates or the SimpleRepository, which makes it easier to find a appropriate example

Suggested you are using ActiveRecord, you can use the linq approach:

```
int page = 0;
int pageSize = 10;

var query = from c in Class.All()
            orderby c.Name
            select c;

var totalPages = (int)(query.Count() / pageSize) + 1;

var paged = query.Skip(page*pageSize).Take(pageSize);

foreach(var item in paged)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
```

or with the QueryTool:

```
var db = new YourDB();
var result = db.Select.From<Class>()
               .Paged(page, pageSize)
               .ExecuteTypedList<Class>();
```

Comment: This works well except it does not allow me to get a TotalCount like using GetPaged does. Any suggestions?

Comment: I added an example. Keep in mind that a linq query is an expression and doesn't hit the database at all. If you call the method Count() subsonic runs a `SELECT COUNT` query. the line `var paged = ...` creates a new IQuerable from the original one and adds some constraints. What you can do too is something like this `var single = paged.Single(x => x.id == 1);`